# Curl installation issue

Tags: xcode, macos, curl

When i issue make command i am getting following error

```
imac@iMac curl-7.73.0 % make                         
Making all in lib
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  all-am
 CC       libcurl_la-altsvc.lo

 rm: .libs/libcurl_la-altsvc.o: Permission denied

 error: unable to open output file '.libs/libcurl_la-altsvc.o':'Operation not permitted'

 1 error generated.

 make[2]: *** [libcurl_la-altsvc.lo] Error 1
 make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
 make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Comment: What are the permissions on .libs/libcurl_la-altsvc.o and the .libs directory?

Comment: May I suggest https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/curl instead?